# Oracle Java 8 "This plug-in is not supported"

Tags: java, plugins

I had Java 7 working nicely on Ubuntu 14.04. Now I have Java 8 (and not Java 7) on a new installation of Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to use Java 8 for the first time today, including adding the URLs to the Exception List, but I haven't been able to get it to run.

https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre gives "This plug-in is not supported".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java NPAPI plugins (of which this is one) no longer work in Google Chrome or Google Chromium. A Java PPAPI plugin is required for these Google browsers.

Java NPAPI plugins continue to work in Mozilla Firefox.

It probably had nothing to do with Java 7 vs Java 8, although I haven't tested it to find out. I installed Java 7, which mean that I have Java 7 **and** Java 8, before discovering that the plugin works in Firefox anyway.